# How to Create Dynamodb Global Secondary Index using AWS CLI?

Tags: command-line, command-line-interface, amazon-dynamodb

The AWS CLI for Dynamodb create-table is a little bit confusion when it comes to create global secondary index. In the [CLI document](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/dynamodb/create-table.html), it says global secondary index could be expressed with the following expression (shorthand):

```
IndexName=string,KeySchema=[{AttributeName=string,KeyType=string},{AttributeName=string,KeyType=string}],Projection={ProjectionType=string,NonKeyAttributes=[string,string]},ProvisionedThroughput={ReadCapacityUnits=long,WriteCapacityUnits=long} ...
```

My interpretation is, I should do

```
--global-secondary-indexes IndexName=requesterIndex,Projection={ProjectionType=ALL},ProvisionedThroughput={ReadCapacityUnits=1,WriteCapacityUnits=1}
```

Note that I am not including KeySchema here to deduce complexity. The console gives me the following error:

```
Parameter validation failed:
Missing required parameter in GlobalSecondaryIndexes[0]: "KeySchema"
Unknown parameter in GlobalSecondaryIndexes[0]: "WriteCapacityUnits", must be one of: IndexName, KeySchema, Projection, ProvisionedThroughput
Invalid type for parameter GlobalSecondaryIndexes[0].ProvisionedThroughput, value: ReadCapacityUnits=1, type: <class 'str'>, valid types: <class 'dict'>
```

So somehow AWS CLI does not recognize the map expression for ProvisionedThroughput. I tried several ways to express it and could not make it work. I also failed to find any web page in Google describing how to do it.

Answer (score 11):

This is the cli call I used to create the Reply sample in the aws documentation from the command line.  The $EP i used at the end can be set in the environment to `EP="--endpoint-url http://localhost:8000"` to create the table on your local dynamodb instead of aws.

```
aws dynamodb create-table --table-name Reply --attribute-definitions \
AttributeName=Id,AttributeType=S AttributeName=ReplyDateTime,AttributeType=S \
AttributeName=PostedBy,AttributeType=S AttributeName=Message,AttributeType=S \
--key-schema AttributeName=Id,KeyType=HASH \
AttributeName=ReplyDateTime,KeyType=RANGE --global-secondary-indexes \
IndexName=PostedBy-Message-Index,KeySchema=["\
{AttributeName=PostedBy,KeyType=HASH}","\
{AttributeName=Message,KeyType=RANGE}"],Projection="{ProjectionType=INCLUDE \
,NonKeyAttributes=["ReplyDateTime"]}",ProvisionedThroughput="\
{ReadCapacityUnits=10,WriteCapacityUnits=10}" --provisioned-throughput \
ReadCapacityUnits=5,WriteCapacityUnits=4 $EP
```

Comment: It would be useful to explain why and how this solves the it.

Comment: The `aws` is terrible for that required pretty stricted data format.

Comment: This worked for me because the examples in the documentation don't quote the KeySchema and ProvisionedThroughput parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Read through [AWS CLI source code on Github](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/blob/develop/awscli/shorthand.py), it could parse double quote content. So adding double quote in the script solved the issue. There is the new code -

```
--global-secondary-indexes IndexName=requesterIndex,Projection={ProjectionType=ALL},ProvisionedThroughput="{ReadCapacityUnits=${CURRENT_READUNIT},WriteCapacityUnits=${CURRENT_WRITEUNIT}}"
```

Comment: Yeah. Your answer is correct! I struggled with same problem. It is sad that in documentation for AWS CLI no good example for Global Secondary Index and you have to spend time to investigate quoting problem.

Answer (score 2):

- Define the table structure in a JSON file, including the index structures. Use following to create a template structure.
  `aws dynamodb create-table --generate-cli-skeleton`
- Run the cli command with the table definition input json
  `aws dynamodb create-table --cli-input-json file://path-to-yourtable-definition.json`